# What happens to neutrons when they are stopped by a material such as lead?

Tags: atomic-physics, neutrons

If neutrons are stopped by a dense material, they are shedding their energy somehow.  Does this mean the lead is becoming a heavier isotope (neutron capture), does the neutron embed itself into the material and turn to hydrogen?  Is there a probabalistic distribution of reactions?

I would like to know for lead, tungesten, and water.  I don't know what to look up but surely for water there are outcomes like deuterium, tritium, hydrogen gas in the water?  If there are tables of these reactions, that would be a great resource.

Comment: The place for data is the Evaluated Nuclear Data Files site at Brookhaven National Lab. Some will get absorbed in to nuclei, many will not and will decay away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A neutron in a block of material can do 3 things each time it passes near a nucleus:

1. Nothing
2. Elastic scattering - transfers some of its kinetic energy to the nucleus
3. Inelastic scattering - the nucleus+neutron turn into several particles, usually liberating several neutrons (fission)
4. Absorption - transmutes the nucleus into a heavier isotope

Variants 3 and 4 are similar, so I just call them "nuclear reaction".

The outcome for every encounter is random. Combining a great number of encounters, these are the possible outcomes:

1. Nothing (if the sheet of material is too thin) - the neutron flies onward
2. Some scattering (if the probability of absorption is low) - the neutron flies out with less kinetic energy and different direction; the material is heated a little
3. Endless scattering (if the probability of absorption is very low, and the block of material is very big) - the neutron's kinetic energy becomes comparable with thermal energy; it wanders among the atoms until it beta-decays
4. Nuclear reaction (if the probability of absorption is significant)

Note that option 3 leads to a proton (positively-charged ion of hydrogen) and a beta particle (an electron with much kinetic energy, which immediately flies away).

If a nuclear reaction occurs, the result has many possibilities:

- A stable heavier nucleus (the case for hydrogen and oxygen, as well as heavier elements)
- A radioactive heavier nucleus (the usual case for heavy elements)
- Several smaller nuclei and/or neutrons (the usual case for uranium-235)

It may be possible to estimate the probability for various outcomes using measured data for neutron cross-sections (see e.g. [here](https://www.ncnr.nist.gov/resources/n-lengths/)): if the absorption cross-section is big when compared to scattering cross-section, the probable outcome is absorption. However, this is complicated by dependence of the cross-section on the neutron's energy.